# Please tell about the query of network packet traversal in linux

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I was reading *Understanding linux networking Internal* book and the pdf *Network packet capture in Linux kernelspace* on the link [networkkernel.pdf](http://beraldoleal.com/talks/networkkernel.pdf)

In the *Understanding linux networking Internal* **under topic 9.2.2** it is given that

> The code that takes care of an input frame is split into two parts: first the driver copies the frame into an input queue accessible by the kernel, and then the kernel processes it (usually passing it to a handler dedicated to the associated protocol such as IP). The first part is executed in interrupt context and can preempt the execution of the second part.

Now the query is when the 2nd part is scheduled? Who schedules them? Is the call given itself in interrupt handler? and in *Network packet capture in Linux kernel space* the  packet input flow is described as:-

```
When working in interrupt driven model, the nic registers an
interrupt handler;
• This interrupt handler will be called when a frame is received;
• Typically in the handler, we allocate sk buff by calling

    dev alloc skb();

• Copies data from nic’s buffer to this struct just created;
• nic call generic reception routine `netif_rx();`
• `netif rx()` put frame in per cpu queue;
• if queue is full, drop!
• net rx action() decision based on skb->protocol;
• This function basically dequeues the frame and delivery a copy
for every protocol handler;
• ptype all and ptype base queues
```

I want to know when  netif rx(); and net rx action() are called? Who call them i mean who schedule them.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This scheduling is done by `NAPI` structure. [Packets](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-11/ftp/pkt_recp/) are cptured by method as descibed. This softirq comes into scenario when there is 'livelock' problem or flood of packet; these are [handled](http://geocitiessites.com/asimshankar/notes/linux-networking-napi.html).

Packet egresses are significantly more complex than packet ingresses, with Queue management and QOS (perhaps even packet-shaping) being implemented. “Queue Discplines” are used to implement user-specifiable [QOS policies](http://linuxeco.com/?p=102).

---

**NAPI Structure Scheduling:**

For NAPI structure is [defined](http://dslab.utdallas.edu/~qasimj/wiki/index.php/Devel/NAPI) as; its driver [Design & Hardware Architecture](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/napi).

Linux uses the ksoftirqd as the general solution to schedule softirq's to run before next interrupt and by putting them under scheduler control. Also this prevents consecutive softirq's from monopolizing the CPU. This also has the effect that the priority of ksoftirq needs to be considered when running very CPU-intensive applications and networking to get the proper balance of softirq/user balance. Increasing ksoftirq priority to 0 (eventually more) is reported to cure problems with low network performance at high CPU load.

There is also a research paper on [NAPI Scheduling](http://www.tnt.dist.unige.it/paper/OR/IPSMOME2004.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Can you explain in detail how NAPI structure maintain scheduling